# Let $(\alpha_\xi\mid\xi<\kappa)$ be a sequence such that $\{\alpha_\xi\mid\xi<\kappa\}=\alpha$. Find an increasing subsequence that has limit $\alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal which is not a cardinal, and $\kappa=|\alpha|$. Then there exists a bijection from $\kappa$ to $\alpha$, or equivalently, a one-to-one sequence  $\langle \alpha_\xi \mid \xi< \kappa \rangle$ of ordinals such that $\{\alpha_\xi \mid \xi< \kappa\}=\alpha$.

My textbook states:

> Now we can find (by transfinite recursion) a subsequence which is strictly increasing and has limit $\alpha$.

I have tried but to no avail in constructing such subsequence, please shed me some lights.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Pick one, then continue picking the least indexed ordinal which is strictly larger.

Comment: @AsafKaragila.  He means ordinal sequence.

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, is it correct that this subsequence is *cofinal* in $\alpha$?

Comment: @William: Yes, and? Your answer is different how?

Comment: @LeAnhDung: Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let K = { a$_t$ : t < $\kappa$ }.

Define, using strong transfinite induction
s$_u$ = min{ a$_t$ in K : for all j < u, s$_j$ < a$_t$ }.