# Increasing subsequence with given limit

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Given a limit ordinal $\alpha$ that is not a cardinal, we can set $\kappa=|\alpha|$ and find a one-to-one sequence $\langle \alpha_\nu\mid\nu<\kappa\rangle$  with range $\alpha$. We want to rigorously construct an *increasing* subsequence with limit $\alpha$.

This [question has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3053563/730592), but I am having difficulties to show that the corresponding subsequence has limit $\alpha$.

I believe one should use the fact that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, but I don't see how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the argument in more detail.

Let $\eta_0=0$. Suppose that $\gamma<\kappa$, and that $\eta_\xi$ has been defined for $\xi<\gamma$ so that $\langle\alpha_{\eta_\xi}:\xi<\gamma\rangle$ is strictly increasing, and if

$$A_\xi=\{\nu<\kappa:\alpha_{\eta_\zeta}<\alpha_\nu\text{ for all }\zeta<\xi\}$$

for each $\xi<\gamma$, then

$$\eta_\xi=\min\{\nu\in A_\xi:\eta_\zeta<\nu\text{ for all }\zeta<\xi\}\,.\tag{1}$$

If $\sup_{\xi<\gamma}\alpha_{\eta_\xi}=\alpha$, we’re done. Otherwise, let

$$A_\gamma=\{\nu<\kappa:\alpha_{\eta_\xi}<\alpha_\nu\text{ for all }\xi<\gamma\}\ne\varnothing\,,$$

and let

$$A_\gamma'=\{\nu\in A_\gamma:\eta_\xi<\nu\text{ for all }\xi<\gamma\}\,.$$

If $A_\gamma'=\varnothing$, then for each $\nu\in A_\gamma$ there is a $\xi<\gamma$ such that $\nu<\eta_\xi$; this violates the minimality of $\eta_\xi$ in $(1)$, so $A_\gamma'\ne\varnothing$, and we set $\eta_\gamma=\min A_\gamma'$. Then $\langle\alpha_{\eta_\xi}:\xi\le\gamma\rangle$ is strictly increasing, and $(1)$ is satisfied for $\xi\le\gamma$, so the recursive construction goes through until at some stage $\gamma$ we have $\sup_{\xi<\gamma}\alpha_{\eta_\xi}=\alpha$, and at that point $\langle\alpha_{\eta_\xi}:\xi<\gamma\rangle$ is the desired subsequence.